# Powershell "get-distributiongroupmember" not returning ALL members

Tags: powershell

I'm working on distribution groups with Powershell, trying to retrieve all members of a distribution group using Get-DistributionGroupMember.

In this distribution group, there are various members, most added from the AD, but also some added from a personal contact list, so NOT part of the AD, not even as a contact object.

Using Get-Distributiongroupmember Powershell will return only members of the distribution group, that are in the AD. Members added from the contact list are NOT returned by powershell.

See images below:

[image]

Two members in the list:

- "Marco Palzkill" is a gmail address from a personal outlook contact list
- "Palzkill, Marco [Gruner + Jahr]" is a normal AD account
  The Outlook Online dialogue shows them both, and they both will recieve eMails sent to the distribution list, also from people sending to the list who do not have the gmail address in their contact list - so it IS inside of the thing.

[image]
Powershell only returns the AD account, not the other one.

Even after removing all AD members from the distribution group, leaving only members added from a contact list, Powershell will just return the distribution group as beeing empty, although the Outlook Online Groups dialogue will still list the members.

Any suggestions in how to get ALL entries of a distribution group?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Piping the results to Select-Object may help : GetDistributionGroup - Identity "VerteilerB$rtlde.onmicrosoft.com" | Select-Object -Property *

Comment: Unfortunately not: It gives out plenty of data, but still only of the AD Account. Thanks though!

Comment: Use Get-DistributionGroup to get all the members.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Okay, but where in there is it stored? Get-Distributiongroup gives me a LOAD of data fields, but I can't see one where the members are actually stored in, only the headers in UMDtmfMap. And on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps it actually says "To view the members of a group, use the Get-DistributionGroupMember cmdlet."

Comment: You can use a foreach like Get-DistributionGroup | foreach{ GetDistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.Identity }

Comment: I tried this - it gives me all members of all distribution groups on the server. Since it's several thousands of groups, I dont really what to do with the result.

Comment: It is not clear what properties you want.  What did you mean by "still only of the AD Account"?

Comment: Okay, trying to be more precise: Distributionlist contains TWO mail addresses: somemail_in_ad@domain.com and somemail_not_in_ad@gmail.com. Get-Distributiongroupmember will only return ONE member: somemail_in_ad@domain.com. How to return somemail_not_in_ad@gmail.com as well?

Comment: Try running powershell as admin. I’ve had differences in output from various cmdlets (AD/exchange) with and without running as admin.

Comment: You can always create an array of emails : $emails = @('somemail_in_ad@domain.com', 'somemail_not_in_ad@gmail.com'); $emails | foreach { Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_ }

Comment: @DougMaurer, sry, no change :(

Comment: If your organization has multiple Active Directory domains, you may need to run the `Set-ADServerSettings` cmdlet with the `ViewEntireForest` parameter set to `$true` before running the `Get-DistributionGroupMember` cmdlet to view the entire forest

Comment: They're not in the AD at all, they're just GMail addresses. They're not a Contact object as well.

Comment: A Distribution Group can only contain AD Objects. Did you try `Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true` ? What membership do you see if viewed with Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC)?